# Spring Data JPA CDI integration fails with Wildfly Swarm

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I'm having an issue getting Spring Data JPA to work in Wildfly Swarm. The first time I attempt to perform an insert, there is a transaction exception. Every subsequent insertion goes through fine. I've tried changing my services' scopes to be `@RequestScope` and `@Stateless` instead of `@ApplicationScope`, I've tried both the entitymanager setups shown here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpd.misc.cdi-integration

I've also tried it with and without the last two lines from the persistence unit config. It still fails in the same way without those.

Also tried the spring `@Transactional` annotation, but that doesn't create a transaction at all (naturally in this context).

Here's the exception trace:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.transactionIsRequired(AbstractEntityManager.java:877)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:579)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:506)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.save(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.proxies.CrudRepository$EmployeeScheduleRepo$1416420309$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.books.employeescheduler.services.EmployeeScheduleService.save(EmployeeScheduleService.java:36)
    at com.books.employeescheduler.services.EmployeeScheduleService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.save$$super(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:77)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:117)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:53)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeAroundInvoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:84)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:68)
    at com.books.employeescheduler.services.EmployeeScheduleService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.books.employeescheduler.services.EmployeeScheduleService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.books.employeescheduler.endpoints.EmployeeScheduleEndpointImpl.save(EmployeeScheduleEndpointImpl.java:33)
    at com.books.employeescheduler.endpoints.EmployeeScheduleEndpointImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.save$$super(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:77)
    at com.books.microservice.core.security.ApiKeySecuredImpl.invoke(ApiKeySecuredImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeAroundInvoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:84)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:68)
    at com.books.employeescheduler.endpoints.EmployeeScheduleEndpointImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.books.employeescheduler.endpoints.EmployeeScheduleEndpointImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.save(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
    ... 34 more
```

And here's my entitymanager for CDI:

```
public class EntityManagerProducer {

    @PersistenceContext
    @Produces
    @Dependent
    public EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

And the class that uses the transaction and calls the save method from the spring data repo:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@ApplicationScoped
@Transactional
public class EmployeeScheduleService {

    @Inject
    private EmployeeScheduleRepo employeeScheduleRepo;

    public EmployeeSchedule save(EmployeeSchedule employeeSchedule) {
        return employeeScheduleRepo.save(employeeSchedule);
    }
}
```

And my persistence unit config:

```
     <persistence-unit name="EmployeeSchedulerUnit">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/EmployeeSchedulerDatasource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:/spring/em"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/spring/emf"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Does the same happen if you instantiate `SimpleJpaRepository(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em)` yourself and call `save(…)`?

Comment: @mp911de You know, it looks like it does work that way. So it is something wrong with how CDI is instantiating an instance of the repo? I'm still not sure how to fix it though, because I'm not sure how to make a producer for the repo interface that actually works.

Comment: Would you care filing an issue in https://jira.spring.io/browse/datajpa/ ? I'll do it otherwise tomorrow.

Comment: @mp911de Created the issue. Thanks for the suggestion! https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-981

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with J2EE + Wildfly 10 environment. Did you resolve this issue? Can you please post an answer to your own question? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in another post: [Spring Data JPA repositories use in EJB timer causes TransactionRequiredException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621679/spring-data-jpa-repositories-use-in-ejb-timer-causes-transactionrequiredexceptio)

As stated in the accepted answer the solution is to put the `@Eager` annotation in the Jpa Repository interface.

Comment: I ended up not getting it fixed, unfortunately, and have since left that company, but good to know what I should've done!